# How extract enum info from elf?

Tags: linux, elf

want to get enum info from elf file. cannot get info from .rodata or .data or .bss section.

1、 `g++ -o t test.cc`

2、`objdump -s -j .rodata t`  or  `objdump -s -j .data t`
shows nothing about enum member data.

gcc version: 4.7.2 and linux centos6

```
namespace test {
    namespace error {
        enum {
            kUnkown         = -1,
            kSuccess        = 0,
            kInvalidParams  = 1,
            kDBInitFailed = 2,
            kTimeout        = 3,
            kAttributeInitFailed = 4,
            kPageCacheInitFailed = 5,
            kUpdate = 9001,
        };  
    } // namespace error
}   

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> want to get enum info from elf file. cannot get info from .rodata or .data or .bss section.

An `enum` is a type declaration, not an object. It doesn't have any presence in memory.

(The same would apply for a `struct` or `union`, or for most `class`es.)

If you compiled your program with debugging symbols enabled (`-g`), there may be some debug information referencing the `enum`. However, that data isn't used at runtime.

Comment: Correct. It definitely *is* present in the debuginfo though. See `eu-readelf --debug-dump=info my-executable-or-lib | grep -A 3 MY_ENUM_SYMBOL`. It's present in the `.debug_info` section. Note that this is only true of true `enum`s; macros used to define constants are NOT available unless compiled with `-g3` or `-ggdb3`, and then you need to use the `.debug_macro` section ... and you have to deal with expanding the macro and evaluating it yourself, which is no fun at all.